# Java - Interface Event-Handling - Delucidation

Tags: java, event-handling

Sorry but this is a concept that I never realized and I never used into my project. I need to learn and use it, absolutly.

So i read many articles about interface and event handling, but it doesnt keep in my mind.

Just start with an easy example :

```
public class Main implements ActionListener{
    JButton but=new JButton("BUTTON");
    public Main() {
        but.addActionListener(this);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // DO SOMETHINGS WHEN THE BUTTON IS CLICKED
    }
}
```

This code is absolutly easy. I implements the ActionListener interface, so i need to write my own code of his method (actionPerformed).

What i dont understand is :

1 - Who implements the `addActionListener` method? Its not a method on JButton class. Who provides this method?

2 - What is the bridge between the `addActionListener` and the actionPerformed method? The first should provide the `Event e` to the second... and both must be implemented somewhere...

Sorry for this question. I try to learn this (by reading many articles on internet) but i can't understand how this can work!

Cheers and thanks to everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - Who implements the addActionListener method? Its not a method on JButton class. Who provides this method?

[JButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) extends [AbstractButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html), inheriting the [addActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) from it.

> 2 - What is the bridge between the addActionListener and the actionPerformed method? The first should provide the Event e to the second... and both must be implemented somewhere...

In simplified terms: when particular area on screen is pressed, AWT event handler thread notifies the UI element located at that area of the screen.

In our case, if the UI element is the button, the button event handling logic loops over the list of action listeners (registered through "addActionListener") and calls "actionPerformed" method in each listener.

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) in The Java Tutorial for information and examples of using buttons.

Comment: Ok the first point :) Point 2 : But how can happen this? I mean, how can it know that must call "actionPerformed" after addActionListener() call? Someone must tell this information...

Comment: It does not call the "actionPerformed" after the "addActionListener" - these are two independent events. "addActionListener" is used just to register all parties that are interested in getting notifications from the particular button. "actionPerformed" is called by a totally different thread (AWT event handler thread) when the particular button is actually pressed.

Answer (score 5):

1. `addActionListener` is implemented by `AbstractButton`, the superclass of `JButton`.
2. The `JButton` object holds a references to your `ActionListener` object (i.e. the instance of your `Main` class). When a UI event is triggered by the user, the `JButton` constructs an `ActionEvent` object and passes it to the stored `ActionListener` object, i.e. it passes the event to your `Main` class.

If you want to go into more detail, then look at the source code for `AbstractButton.addActionListener` to see what it does.

Comment: Yes, in fact i just see that :) there is listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, l); Ok, so i pass to this method (add of listenerList) the class where there is the button (Main). Now i left to know who call actionPerformed :)

Comment: If you want to know who is calling "actionPerformed", you could just put a breakpoint in the "actionPerformed" method and check the call stack (or print out a stacktrace)

Comment: @markzzz: `JButton` (or its superclasses) call `actionPerformed()`, they're responsible for knowing who to notify when the user presses the button.

Comment: Uhm...but just for clearity. When i call but.addActionListener(this); , the this is meant as instance of the Main (Class) or the Interface? (sorry the tag shouldnt be so clear, but i don't know how to use the <code> tag here :))

Comment: @markzzz: Your `Main` class implements `ActionListener`, and so you're passing the `Main` object to `addActionListener`. It might help to clarify things for you if you implemented `ActionListener` in a seperate class, and pass an instance of that to `addActionListener`, rather than implementing it on `Main`.

Comment: @markzzz As your Main class implements ActionListener interface, then it is also "instance of that interface". So, the button will call the same instance that you added with "addActionListener" method. In your case, that would be the instance of the Main class.

Comment: Yeah ok..that was clear! I still don't understand how this can work :) For example, addActionListener method (implemented on AbstractButton) should get an ActionListener object (so an interface)? But it get a Main class... :)

Comment: @markzzz: Because `Main` *is* an `ActionListener` - it implements the interface. Your difficulties in understanding don't lie in the `ActionListener` and associated code, but with a more fundamental conception of what Java interfaces are.

Comment: Your Main class implements the ActionListener interface, so in addition to being an instance of Main class, it is also an instance of that interface. Seems to me you need to read up on Java interfaces: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 1):

> Who implements the addActionListener
>   method? Its not a method on JButton
>   class. Who provides this method?

`addActionListener` is a method on the `AbstractButton` parent class.

> What is the bridge between the
>   addActionListener and the
>   actionPerformed method? The first
>   should provide the Event e to the
>   second... and both must be implemented
>   somewhere...

The class that implements the `ActionListener` method implements `actionPerformed`.  It's the one that wishes to be notified about and respond to events.

Comment: Thanks to your reply :) Fine, actionPerformed is the one that wishes to be notified, but why that method? Who said "use actionPerformed" and not somethings others? :)

Comment: The interface demands it.  If you don't implement that method the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is answered, so answering the second: the bridge is `JButton.setActionCommand(String command);` and `ActionEvent.getActionCommand();`. This is useful when an actionlistener listens for multiple buttons.

Comment: Uhm Thanks. Is still don't understand the relationship from the Main class and the Interface... :)

Comment: @markzzz Which part? You can implement `ActionListener` anywhere else, or as an anonymous class.

Comment: this : When i'll implements my own event handler/interface, i'll pass to the addSomeListener the instance of my "formal" class (that implements method of SomeListener (for example actionReturned). How can I call that actionReturned to the class that demand that resource?